# How to extract a line before a regex match?

Tags: javascript, regex

im trying to extract the `shop title` and `address` before an `address regex match`. I've been stuck for a while. Thanks! Eventually I want to get the telephone as well but im not sure how. Can someone help me with this?

**Function:**

```
function getShopInfo(text) {

const addrRegex = /[0-9]+.+(Singapore\s+\d{6}|S\d{6})/g;
const titleRegex = `/(.*\n){1}${addrRegex}/`; // extract the title before the address
if (text.match(titleRegex)) {
    const title = text.match(titleRegex);
    console.log(title);
    console.log(addr);
    console.log("\n")
  } else {
    console.log('Message: No TITLE before ADDRESS found!');
  }

}
```

**Text:**

```
LOCATE US
Din Tai Fung (Singapore, Thailand and United Kingdom) is managed by Taster Food Pte Ltd.
Din Tai Fung Singapore: We regret to inform that online/email reservations are not accepted. Please 
Name
Contact
Email
Subject
Restaurant
Message
SINGAPORE RESTAURANTS TEL
Paragon
290 Orchard Road #B1-03 Singapore 238859+65 6836 8336
BreadTalk IHQ
30 Tai Seng Street #01-02 Singapore 534013
+65 6702 0060
City Square Mall
180 Kitchener Road #01-10 Singapore 208539
+ 65 6634 2322
Chinatown Point
133 New Bridge Road #02-01 Singapore 059413
+65 6534 2722
```

**Final Output:**

```
Paragon
290 Orchard Road #B1-03 Singapore 238859

BreadTalk IHQ
30 Tai Seng Street #01-02 Singapore 534013

City Square Mall
180 Kitchener Road #01-10 Singapore 208539

Chinatown Point
133 New Bridge Road #02-01 Singapore 059413
```

Comment: I'd use the following regex for the test cases so far `(.*)\n(\d+.*Singapore\s+\d{6})`, which makes assumption that address is only 1 line and the title (or non-address line) appears before the address. If you want something better, you should include more test cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use just a single pattern: capture the title in the first capture group (everything on its line), and on the next line, capture a digit at the beginning of the line, eventually followed by `Singapore`, with

```
(.+)\n(\d+.*Singapore \d{6}\b)
```

https://regex101.com/r/VEKqjw/1

```js
const input = `LOCATE US
Din Tai Fung (Singapore, Thailand and United Kingdom) is managed by Taster Food Pte Ltd.
Din Tai Fung Singapore: We regret to inform that online/email reservations are not accepted. Please 
Name
Contact
Email
Subject
Restaurant
Message
SINGAPORE RESTAURANTS TEL
Paragon
290 Orchard Road #B1-03 Singapore 238859+65 6836 8336
BreadTalk IHQ
30 Tai Seng Street #01-02 Singapore 534013
+65 6702 0060
City Square Mall
180 Kitchener Road #01-10 Singapore 208539
+ 65 6634 2322
Chinatown Point
133 New Bridge Road #02-01 Singapore 059413
+65 6534 2722`;
for (const [, title, address] of input.matchAll(/(.+)\n(\d+.*Singapore \d{6}\b)/g)) {
  console.log(title)
  console.log(address);
}
```

Or, without `matchAll`:

```js
const input = `LOCATE US
Din Tai Fung (Singapore, Thailand and United Kingdom) is managed by Taster Food Pte Ltd.
Din Tai Fung Singapore: We regret to inform that online/email reservations are not accepted. Please 
Name
Contact
Email
Subject
Restaurant
Message
SINGAPORE RESTAURANTS TEL
Paragon
290 Orchard Road #B1-03 Singapore 238859+65 6836 8336
BreadTalk IHQ
30 Tai Seng Street #01-02 Singapore 534013
+65 6702 0060
City Square Mall
180 Kitchener Road #01-10 Singapore 208539
+ 65 6634 2322
Chinatown Point
133 New Bridge Road #02-01 Singapore 059413
+65 6534 2722`;
const pattern = /(.+)\n(\d+.*Singapore \d{6}\b)/g;
let match;
while (match = pattern.exec(input)) {
  const [, title, address] = match;
  console.log(title)
  console.log(address);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @CertainPerformance. May i know what is [, title, address] in the while loop? im not getting the first comma.

Comment: That's destructuring. It takes the `[1]` and `[2]` indicies from the match array and puts them into the two variable names `title` and `address` (while discarding the `[0]` index - that's why there's nothing before the first comma)

Comment: You made it perfectly clear. Im accepting this as the answer. Thanks @CertainPerformance